# Loop with odd numbers in lesscss

Tags: css, loops, less

is it possible to loop only odd numbers in less css?

currently to loop all numbers I'm using something like this:

```
  .loop(@n, @i: 1) when(@i =< @n){
    :nth-child(@{i}){
      z-index: @n - @i;
    }

    .loop(@n, (@i + 1));
  }   

  .loop(15);
```

but I want to generate rules only for 1, 3, 5, 7...

Comment: What about `:nth-child(odd) {/*...*/}` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work:

```
  .loop(@n, @i: 1) when(@i =< @n){
    :nth-child(@{i}){
      z-index: @n - @i;
    }

    .loop(@n, (@i + 2));
  }   

  .loop(15);
```

The result should be what you want ie: `1, 3, 5, 7...`